# How to upload a file from a server to a Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-iam

I have owner access on the server. In file storage, I have storage admin access. I've tried with the two commands below to upload a file into a Cloud Storage bucket:

```
$gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M cp test_091219.pgsql gs://test_file_storage
```

and

```
$gsutil cp test_091219.pgsql gs://test_file_storage
```

but both the times, I am getting the same error as below:

> Copying file://test_091219.pgsql
>   [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
>       ResumableUploadAbortException: 403 Insufficient Permission
>       ResumableUploadAbortException: 403 Insufficient Permission
>       ResumableUploadAbortException: 403 Insufficient Permission
>       ResumableUploadAbortException: 403 Insufficient Permission
>       ResumableUploadAbortException: 403 Insufficient Permission
>       CommandException: Some temporary components were not uploaded successfully. Please retry this upload.

If you have any ideas on how to resolve this error, please share them with me.

Comment: Do you have a service account? Is a one shot transfer or recurring transfert?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the bucket is public you will need to provide some sort of authentication to be able to interact with it.

[Install in the Gcloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/) in your server and [run the command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login)

```
gcloud auth login
```

With an account with sufficient permissions to write files into the bucket.

In order to be able to create new objects within the bucket you need the permission `storage.objects.create`. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions) you can find a list with all the possible permissions for Cloud Storage.